# Android Kotlin Coroutines: Have to do background task which require context and after completion only I have to execute next conditions

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have to delete some sqlite records from table which require activity context as its a long running operation but after completion only I have to execute next code which havee certain if conditions.

How to achieve the same. If I put withContext and Dispatchers.IO, It stuck my screen for sometime. Sometime it will crash the application.

Please suggest with some sample code.

Answer (score 1):

To perform a long-running SQLite database operation in the background and execute subsequent code only after the operation is complete, you can use Kotlin coroutines and the `withContext` function to switch to a background thread (typically `Dispatchers.IO`) for the database operation. Here's a sample code snippet demonstrating how to achieve this:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext

// ...

suspend fun deleteRecordsAndPerformNextAction(context: Context) {
    // Switch to a background thread
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        // Perform your SQLite database operation here (e.g., delete records)
        val database = YourDatabaseHelper(context)
        database.deleteRecords()

        // Continue with any additional background work here if needed
        // ...

        // Once the database operation is complete, switch back to the main thread
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            // Update the UI or execute subsequent code
            if (condition1) {
                // Execute code for condition1
            } else if (condition2) {
                // Execute code for condition2
            } else {
                // Execute code for other conditions
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this code:

1. We start by switching to a background thread (`Dispatchers.IO`) using `withContext` to perform the long-running database operation. Replace `YourDatabaseHelper` with the actual class you use to interact with your SQLite database.
2. Inside the background thread block, you can execute any database-related operations, such as deleting records.
3. If you have additional background work to perform after the database operation (e.g., additional data processing or computations), you can do it within the same background thread block.
4. After completing the background work, we switch back to the main thread (`Dispatchers.Main`) using `withContext` to update the UI or execute subsequent code.

Remember to replace the comments and placeholders in the code with your actual logic. This approach ensures that long-running operations won't block the main thread, preventing ANR (Application Not Responding) errors and keeping your app responsive.

Comment: Thanks @Akk_, I will try above approach. Earlier I thought, we were not able to access Dispatchers.Main inside Dispatchers.IO,  which restrict me to use above approach but now its clear me.